Who used the term "existential quantifier" in his work for the first time in the history of mathematical logic?
Who used the term "existential quantifier" in his work for the first time in the history of mathematical logic?
I am sure that Peirce did not use the term in his book "Studies in Logic" in 1883 or in his work "On the algebra of logic" in the "American Journal of Mathematics" No.7 in 1885.
So, who was the first to use it?

[ OP clarified, in what was intended to be a comment: “I want to know the first user of the term ‘existential quantifier’ in English as a natural language.” ]

You might also want to try https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

The OED gives two early citations for “quantifier”.  One is C.S. Peirce in American Journal of Mathematics vol. 7 197, which you say you have already checked, so I suppose the issue is that he used “quantifier” but not “existential quantifier”. The OED also suggests A. De Morgan in Transactions Cambridge Philos. Society vol. 10 471 (1864).  Have you looked at that?  It might have the same problem, but you might also hit the jackpot.

I looked now at "A. De Morgan in Transactions Cambridge Philos. Society" vol. 10.  But unfortunately there was no expression "existential quantifier".

According to https://math.hawaii.edu/~tom/history/set.html :
Existence (existential quantifier). Peano used the symbol $\exists$
for existence in volume II, number 1, of his Formulaire de mathematiqus, which was published in 1897 (Cajori vol. 2, page 300).

+1 - to be fair, the symbol was used by Peano with a different meaning: $\text {Class}(a) \to (\exists a \equiv a \ne \Lambda)$, where $\Lambda$ is the empty class (slightly modified symbols). Thus, the reading of Peano's $\exists a$ is "class $a$ is not empty" i.e. "there are $a$'s".

True , @MauroALLEGRANZA , the symbol & the meaning has been "slightly" varying over 125 years.

This doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was not about the $\exists$ sign, but about «the term "existential quantifier"».

That term has been in use since Aristotle , Eg https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/ , where we see "all A is B" & "some A is B" which is "there exists some A which is B" , @MJD , there were no Symbols that time, I am not sure what OP wants.

OP added in  a reply, now deleted, that they want “to know the first user of the term “existential quantifier” in English as a natural language.”.

It would be Aristotle , whose works involving that "Concept" [ maybe with or without that "term" ] have English translations. In case translations are disqualified , @MJD , Hilbert & Co would be disqualified too & we will have to look for English writers,

There are no "qusntifier" terms in Aristotle, for sure. The current translation of the Greek text is "B belongs to some A". Obviously we can read it as corresponding to the modern symbolic form that uses quantifiers...

That is right : Depending on how we Interpret the Concept & how we translate it [ with English or with Symbol or with Modernism ] the answer will change , @MauroALLEGRANZA , Otherwise we have to check English writers. OP will have to clarify !

As per answer above, the symbol was used by Peano in formula: $\text {Class}(a) → (∃a ≡ a≠ \Lambda)$, where $\Lambda$ is the empty class (slightly modified symbols).
Thus, Peano's $∃a$ means "class $a$ is not empty" i.e. "there are $a$'s".
Early use of "quantifiers" without qualification, is C.S.Peirce, The Logic of Relatives in The Monist (1897).
Another early source is Clarence Irving Lewis, A Survey of Symbolic Logic (1918) that has "quantifiers" for the "algebraic" versions: $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$" without further qualifications; see page 97 for their definitions and page 99 for the term.
The symbols became connom around mid 1930s: a good reference can be the English translation (1937) of Hilbert & Ackermann's textbook (German edition 1929), page 59:

"we shall introduce a special 'existential quantifier'..."

In conclusion, it is reasonable to assume that the Hilbertian "Seinzeichen" (Existence-sing) of 1920s transformed into "Existenzzeichen" and "existentiellen Quantor" form which some American scholar that studied in Germany in the late 1920s (maybe Church) imported the term and translated it into English as "existential quantifier".
